# Reliability of Google Analytics data

Tags: ios, analytics

I have developed an **iOS** game and currently the game is in beta phase. I have integrated **Google Analytics (GA**) to understand the users' behavior. I am distributing the game to my beta testers using **TestFlight**.

Recently, I found that number of sessions shown by TestFlight data is not matching with that of GA's data.

I have following questions:

1. Is GA's data is more **reliable** than the TestFlight's data?
2. Is GA suitable analytics solution for mobile games? If not, what are the reasons for that? Is **Firebase** analytics more reliable compared to GA?
3. I am looking for an analytics solution which can help to analyze behavior of each user (per user tracking instead of aggregated data). Can Firebase analytics provide this feature?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.